# Setting parameters for a Symfony2 Dependency Injection service

Tags: php, dependency-injection, symfony

Seems to be a very basic question, but I can't find the answer (probably I'm thinking in the wrong direction):

My services are defined in a YML file.

```
PurchaseService:
class: Application_Service_Doctrine_PurchaseService  
calls:
- [ setPurchaseRepository, [ @purchase.repository] ]

purchase.repository:      
class: Application_Repository_Doctrine_PurchaseRepository

archive.repository:      
class: Application_Repository_Doctrine_ArchiveRepository
```

In a certain case I want to inject archive.repository instead of purchase.repository.
How? (Note: I'm not using the complete Symfony2 framework, just the DI Container within a Zend Framework project)

Comment: In which case do you want to switch ?

Answer (score 1):

You could just define the service under a second name?

```
ArchiveService:
  class: Application_Service_Doctrine_PurchaseService
  calls:
    - [ setArchiveRepository, [@archive.repository] ]
```

Then your client code would surely know which Service it needed? You could farm out which service to pull from the DIC into a factory class (or use a control statement, whatever suits your needs)?